# Using a for loop to imitate a select statement outputs uneven columns when colors added

Tags: bash, for-loop, colors, multiple-columns

I have an array of over 100 elements. I need a menu to list these elements and then I need to select one of these elements for use further into the script. Easy enough..

```
select opt in "${menu[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
        [0-9]*) # do stuff with $opt
    esac
done
```

But as far as I can tell, other than `$COLULMN` width, there seems to be no way of customizing the way `select` outputs a menu. So I thought I'd use a `for` loop to imitate `select` and add a little bit of color to the menu.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

bold(){
    printf '%b' "\033[38;1m$@\033[0m"
}

mapfile -t options < <(gshuf -n50 /usr/share/dict/words)
n=${#options[@]}
i=0

until [[ $i -eq $n ]]; do
    for opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        i=$((i+1))
        bold "$i) "
        echo "$opt"
    done
done | column
```

This does allow me to colorize the menu but it also messes up the columns structure

For example, this is how it would look with without color

```
1) sowt                 40) priorate            79) Arakanese
2) pachysomia           41) poudrette           80) mesenchyma
3) somnivolency         42) magnifice           81) deconsideration
4) gargoyle             43) cautionry           82) meliorable
```

and this is how looks with color

```
1) sowt  40) priorate           79) Arakanese
2) pachysomia           41) poudrette           80) mesenchyma
3) somnivolency         42) magnifice           81) deconsideration
4) gargoyle             43) cautionry           82) meliorable
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening and is there a way to simply colorize the numbers of a numbered list without breaking the columns/formatting etc? Is it is possible to do this with `select`? That would be ideal.

Comment: Maybe `column` doesn't know that the special characters \033 et al. just change colours and counts them as displayable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `column` command doesn't know the escape sequences takes no space in the output, but you can use `sed` to add the sequences after the `column` command, for example:

```
shuf -n 50 /usr/share/dict/words \
 | nl -nln -s") " -w1 \
 | column \
 | sed "s/[0-9]\+/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/g"
```

Or:

```
shuf -n 50 /usr/share/dict/words \
 | nl -nln -s") " -w1 \
 | column -c $COLUMNS \
 | sed "s/[0-9]\+/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/g"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak it a bit to get the output displayed correctly: `gshuf -n200 /usr/share/dict/words | nl -nln -s") " -w3  |  sed -E 's/[ ]+)/)/g' | column -c $COLUMNS  | gsed "s/[0-9]\+/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/g"`. But this works well. Thanks again!